# JOOQ parsing orderBy and orderDirection to use with dslcontext

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm getting orderBy and orderDirection from my controller and want to parse it and use it with my repository where I'm using DSLContext to query.

Here is my method:

```java
public List<Map<String, Object>> read(@NonNull final String schema,
                                      @NonNull final String tableName,
                                      @NonNull final List<String> columnNames,
                                      @NonNull final String queryConditions,
                                      @NonNull final String orderBy,
                                      @NonNull final String orderDirection) {
    final Table table = table(getTableWithSchema(schema, tableName));
    final List<Condition> conditions = conditionMapper.mapToConditions(queryConditions);
    final List<Field<?>> fields = fieldsMapper.mapToFields(columnNames);
    final SortField sortField = ???

    return crudRepository.read(table, fields, conditions, sortField);
}
```

Where later on my crud calls it as:

```java
public List<Map<String, Object>> read(@NonNull final Table<?> table,
                                      @NonNull final Collection<Field<?>> fields,
                                      @NonNull final Collection<Condition> conditions,
                                      @NonNull final SortField<?> sortField) {
    return dslContext
            .select(fields)
            .from(table)
            .where(conditions)
            .orderBy(sortField)
            .fetchMaps();
}
```

How would I go about creating that sortField (only one) so I can pass that to dslContext?

Comment: Just to be sure, since you're working with `String` types (and since I'm paranoid): Your controller does not pass user input to your `read()` method, right?

Comment: No, its an internal tool used only by admins - its used by another API that validates parameters etc

Comment: As I said, I'm paranoid. If the `String` values originate from outside of your logic (through an API, UI, doesn't matter), you're exposing a SQL injection vulnerability here. I strongly suggest you sanitise your inputs *yourself*, instead of relying on "another API".

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself - JOOQ beginner here so maybe it will help someone out.

```
SortField<?> sortField = DSL.field(orderBy).sort(SortOrder.valueOf(orderDirection));
```